# Append a new cell (row) at the end of specific column in google spreadsheet using api

Tags: google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api, google-api-client

Could not figure out a way to append data at the end of specific column in google sheets through v4 APIs.

I know we can append a completely new row using Append API: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/writing#append_values

But this adds a completely new row starting from 1st column. I need to push/append data starting from specific column only.

Like following is the sheet I am working on:

[image: My Sample Sheet]

Now I need to add multiple categories like "Ca1" and "Cat2" to the Categories column. I know I can pass data for not to be filled/edited columns as null like:

```
"majorDimension": "ROWS",
"values": [ 
           [null,"Cat1",null]
           [null,"Cat2",null]
          ]
```

But after this, if next time I need to append data to Tags column (say Tag1, Tag2) only using the same format, the resulting sheet would become:

```
"majorDimension": "ROWS",
    "values": [ 
               [null,null,"Tag1"]
               [null,null,"Tag2"]
              ]
```

[image: Resulting sheet]

And hence empty spaces in between like C6 cell will increase if there is no solution, once data becomes huge. I need to maintain the data like this only (column-wise only).

Is there any solution to append data at the end of a specific column?

Comment: Are you using the Sheets advance service in Google Apps Script or are you interacting with the Sheets API elsewhere?

Comment: @Marios  Rolledback as the question has no indication  of using apps script. If you want to add a apps script alternative answer and you think the tag is relevant, you should add the tag and not remove existing relevant tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can determine the next empty cell using the existing values and then define your range from there.

1. Get the column [values](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get)

```
GET https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}/values/C:C
```

2. Response is a [ValueRange](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values#ValueRange), which includes an array of values. Thankfully, "empty trailing rows and columns will not be included", so you can use that to your advantage.

```
var lastRow = ValueRange.values.length;
```

3. Specify your new range selecting only the next empty cell in column C

```
var range = 'Sheet1!C' + (lastRow+1);
```

4. Send your [update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update) request

```
Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update(
  {
    'majorDimension': 'COLUMNS',
    'values': [['Tag1']]
  },
  spreadsheetId,
  range, 
  { valueInputOption: 'USER_ENTERED' }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Assuming that:**

- `sheet` is a *sheet object* (e.g. `SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet1");`),
- column *C* (`3`) is the column you want to paste the data in,
- Column *C* does not have empty cells between *C1* and the last *C* value with content.
- `data` has the following format:

  ```
  data = [ 
              ["Tag1"]
              ["Tag2"],
              ...
             ]
  ```

then you can use this generic expression:

```
const cSize=sheet.getRange('C:C').getValues().filter(String).length; 

sheet.getRange(cSize+1,3,data.length,1).setValues(data);
```

where [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns).